# /opt directory doesn't exist on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, folders

Just received my macbook air and discover that i can't run port command because of /opt directory not exists. Is it normal? (OS X 10.9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, OS X does not come with anything in /opt or even the directory itself. I presume you're looking for [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), which is a 3<sup>rd</sup>-party package manager that installs `port`. MacPorts has to be installed separately.

Various other apps can place files in /opt though. For example, even though I've never had MacPorts, I have the /opt directory and it contains the X11 directory.

Comment: keep in mind that there are also other Projects like homebrew and fink.

Comment: @konqui Homebrew hasn't put anything in my /opt—have you used a custom prefix?

Comment: No i have not but i saw soe tutorials where they show how one could do. Your right by default homebrew doean't use /opt. But one can make it to use it, thats why i mentioned it.